# Find the value of the question below

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

If $x^{3}+\frac{1}{x^{3}}=14$

Find the value of $$x^{6}+\frac{1}{x^{6}}$$

---

**Original Question:**

If $x^{2}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}=14$

Find the value of $$x^{5}+\frac{1}{x^{5}}$$

Comment: I know the answer, just sharing a new information

Comment: @Dr.MV thank you very much. I know how to improve it. thanks

Comment: Did this question change? It seems to not match some of the answers. If so, could you please include the earlier version as an edit?

Comment: This question has been edited three times, each time invalidating the previously posted answers. OP seems eager to share a lot of new information with us.

Comment: @OP: It is considered inappropriate behavior on this site to "recycle" questions.  Continuing such actions is likely grounds for suspension.

Comment: In case you need a confirmation, here's the word from your friendly moderator. DO NOT REPLACE AN EXISTING QUESTION WITH ANOTHER ONE. This is considered rude to the people who answered the original version, because you make their posts look out of place. Remember, the answers are not just for you - they are (mostly ?) for the benefit of all the future readers of this thread.

Answer (score 11):

We have
\begin{align*}
x^5+\frac{1}{x^5}&=\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left(x^4-x^2+1-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^4}\right)\\
&=\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left[\left(x^4+2+\frac{1}{x^4}\right)-\left(x^2+2+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+1\right]\\
&=\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)\left[\left(14\right)^2-\left(16\right)+1\right]\\
&=181\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)
\end{align*}
Also,
\begin{align*}
\left|x+\frac{1}{x}\right|&=\sqrt{\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2}=\sqrt{x^2+2+\frac{1}{x^2}}=\sqrt{16}=4
\end{align*}
Then
$$x^5+\frac{1}{x^5}=-724\text{ or }724$$

---

On the other hand,
$$x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}=14\implies x^6+\frac{1}{x^6}=\left(x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}\right)^2-2=(14)^2-2=194$$

Comment: Well done!! A +1

Comment: I knew you could just push it through by multiplying by $x^2$ and then substituting what you got into the second equation, but this is the elegant solution to be desired.

Comment: For questions of this type the key is to observe that the truly interesting variable is $x+\dfrac1x$ - not $x$ itself. +1 for making that observation.

Answer (score 8):

Multiply the entire expression by $x^2$, and you get $x^4 +1=14 x^2$. Next, substitute $u=x^2$, and you find $u^2-14 u +1 = 0$. Use the quadratic formula to solve for $u$, and you find $u=\frac{14\pm\sqrt{14^2 -4}}{2}$. Use this to solve for $x$. (Don't forget that x may have either sign here, since $u=x^2$)

Comment: ah, thank you. (corrected)

Comment: The brute force is just as effective here as others. +1

Comment: Just like in the NFL. That and I have a tricky (research-related) question that has been bothering me for a few weeks. I need to up my rep to put a good bounty on it. =P

Answer (score 7):

You can think of this in terms of symmetric polynomials. Let $y=1/x$ then you have:

$$x^2+y^2=14\\xy=1$$

So $$(x+y)^2=14+2\cdot 1=16$$ or $$x+y=\pm 4.$$

Now, 
$$\begin{align}x^5+y^5&=(x+y)(x^4-x^3y+x^2y^2-xy^3+y^4)\\
&=(x+y)(x^4+y^4+(xy)^2 - xy(x^2+y^2))\\
&=(x+y)\left((x^2+y^2)^2 - x^2y^2-xy(x^2+y^2)\right)
\end{align}$$
Using $x^2+y^2=14$ and $xy=1$ we have:

$$x^5+y^5=(x+y)(14^2-1-14)=\pm 4\cdot 181$$

Comment: Very nice! I love how this method can be so easily generalized to other problems!

Answer (score 4):

For the newer problem, the OP asks if $x^3+x^{-3}=14$, then what is $x^6+x^{-6}$.  This one is a bit easier than the earlier post.

Note that we have

$$\left(x^3+x^{-3}\right)^2=x^6+x^{-6}+2\implies x^6+x^{-6}=(14)^2-2=194$$

and we're done.

Comment: As the OP is changed from time to time...

$$x^p + 1/x^p = 14 \Rightarrow x = \sqrt[p]{ - 7 \pm 4 \sqrt{3} }$$

So

$$x^q + 1/x^q = \big( - 7 \pm 4 \sqrt{3} \big)^{q/p} + 1 / \big( - 7 \pm 4 \sqrt{3} \big)^{q/p}$$